# Scala Macros: Generated class fails to compile with unimplemented members

Tags: scala, macros, scala-macro-paradise

My problem is that my generated class' members are not getting recognised as implemented. This is being built for Scala 2.10/2.11/2.12 with 2.11 being the default. Using macroparadise 2.10.

Goal of this was to mark the some traits as **freezable** and generate an implementation class for each that takes `scala.util.Try` for each method that is freezable that will have its `get` method called when accessing the data. All unfreezable methods are filled in with `throw new IllegalStateException`.  And a custom `freeze` method is created that creates an instance of the `Frozen` class filled in with the data needed using the methods defined by the trait.

I have set up an annotation macro to be placed on **traits** and generate a **companion object** with an inner class called `Frozen` like below:

```
{
  abstract trait JavaInfo extends scala.AnyRef {
    @new CanFreeze() def isJavaInfo: Boolean;
    @new CannotFreeze() def toJavaInfo: AnyRef
  };
  object JavaInfo extends scala.AnyRef {
    def <init>() = {
      super.<init>();
      ()
    };
    class Frozen extends JavaInfo with java.io.Serializable {
      <paramaccessor> private val $isJavaInfo: scala.util.Try[Boolean] = _;
      def <init>($isJavaInfo: scala.util.Try[Boolean]) = {
        super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      override def isJavaInfo: Boolean = this.$isJavaInfo.get;
      override def toJavaInfo: AnyRef = throw new IllegalStateException("Method not frozen!")
    };
    def freeze(valueToFreeze: JavaInfo): Frozen = new Frozen(scala.util.Try.apply(valueToFreeze.isJavaInfo))
  };
  ()
}
```

The following error occurs when I try to run my macro on the trait `JavaInfo`:

```
[error] /Users/senk/projects/scala-debugger/scala-debugger-api/src/main/scala/org/scaladebugger/api/profiles/traits/info/JavaInfo.scala:9: class Frozen needs to be abstract, since:
[error] it has 2 unimplemented members.
[error] /** As seen from class Frozen, the missing signatures are as follows.
[error]  *  For convenience, these are usable as stub implementations.
[error]  */
[error]   override def isJavaInfo: Boolean = ???
[error]   override def toJavaInfo: AnyRef = ???
[error] @Freezable trait JavaInfo {
[error]  ^
[error] one error found
```

The trait itself is as follows:

```
import org.scaladebugger.macros.freeze.{CanFreeze, CannotFreeze, Freezable}

@Freezable trait JavaInfo {
  @CanFreeze def isJavaInfo: Boolean
  @CannotFreeze def toJavaInfo: AnyRef
}
```

Get error that nothing has been implemented by the `Frozen` class, even though I see the implementation in the tree I'm building.

Code in question is here: https://github.com/chipsenkbeil/scala-debugger/blob/AddFreezableMacroSupport/scala-debugger-macros/src/main/scala/org/scaladebugger/macros/freeze/FreezableMacro.scala

You can test the failure by checking out that branch and running `sbt scalaDebuggerApi/compile`, which will compile the macros project for Scala 2.11 followed by the API itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I was creating the methods and implementing their bodies, but reusing the old modifiers of each method and just tacking on the `Flag.OVERRIDE: FlagSet`. Turns out unimplemented methods have a `Flag.DEFERRED` on them, so I was producing a `Modifiers(OVERRIDE | DEFERRED)`, which didn't make sense considering it had a body. Seems that having the modifier of `DEFERRED` will cause the compiler to ignore the body when checking the method, even though the body will show up in the byte code itself.